# freeradius to determine cisco shell privilege based on AD group

Tags: linux, openldap, cisco, freeradius

I have FreeRadius configured with Active Directory and looks for a users groups, the last thing I need to do is is similar to the following.

All tutorials on the internet refer the users file (which I am not using) and they would have something similar to this:

```
 youruser   Cleartext-Password := "somepass"
 Service-Type = NAS-Prompt-User,
 cisco-avpair = "shell:priv-lvl=15"
```

So in my sites-available/default file in the post-auth section I created some if statements such as:

```
if(LDAP-Group == "CN=groupname, ou=blah, ou=blah"){
   Service-Type = Administrative-User, cisco-avpair = "shell:priv-lvl=15"
}
else {
  reject
}
```

When I run it it complains about the Service-type ... line inside the if statement saying

```
Unknown action 'Administrative-User,'.
Error parsing post-auth section
```

any ideas how to fix this

Answer (score 1):

Something like that in "post-auth" section

```
   if (LDAP-Group == "SomeGroup") {
                   update reply {
                    cisco-avpair = "shell:priv-lvl=15",
                   }

    }
    else {
            reject
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this with ntlm_auth, with the --required-membership-of=+somegroup

Notice that the "+" is the separator.  The limitation with using ntlm_auth is that you can only require a single group, unlike other options which may give you a few groups to try.  However, in my case, the "network_admins" group is the only one that will ever pass.

Answer (score 0):

Like this; in sites-enabled/default

```
authenticate {
            Auth-Type ntlm_auth {
                    ntlm_auth
         if (ok) {
            update reply {
            Service-Type = Administrative-User,  
                        }  
                     }
```